# Change bot nickname (Discord js) in a guild where a command was executed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a free public bot soon but I have some troubles rn.
I am trying to use a command (example: -bitcoin) that makes the bot change its name every 30 seconds ONLY in the guild (bot nickname), but when making a function and looping it to make this possible, the bot can't get the guild id again because there's no message being replied in the 2nd and further times.

```js
if(command === 'bitcoin'){
  updateNickname(message);
  setInterval(updateNickname, 30000);
}

async function updateNickname(message) {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=eur`);
  return message.guild.me.setNickname(`BTC = ${data.bitcoin.eur}€`);
}
```

Can someone help me?

DISCLAIMER: I can't just cache an id, because it wouldn't work on other servers, it would only work in the server id I texted in, so I want it to work on multiple server at the same time (in further development, people will be able to choose their own cypto and currency for individual servers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably persist this data in a database (since I guess you want this to persist between bot restarts).

Then, I will have 1 interval to run every 30 seconds that will update all the guilds at once. This should also be easier on your bot since you don't have a different interval for each guild this bot is installed on.

```js
if(command === 'bitcoin'){
  updateNickname(message.guild, message.data);
  await persistInDatabase({
    guildId: message.guild.id
    coin: message.data
  });
}

// run this every 30 seconds.
setInterval(updateNicknames, 30000);

// change nickname for a single guild
async function updateNickname(guild, coin) {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=eur`);
  return guild.me.setNickname(`BTC = ${data.bitcoin.eur}€`);
}

// change nickname for ALL guilds this bot is installed on
async function updateNicknames() {
  const allGuilds = await getAllFromDb();
  for(let dbGuild of allGuilds) {
    const guild = client.guilds.get(dbGuild.guildId);
    updateNickname(guild, dbGuild.coin);
  }
}
```

- I didn't include the database function, but it should be straightforward. Just choose your favorite database :-)
- I saved the coin type in the database, but if you don't need it, you can remove it.
- You can cache the axios call just so you won't do it for each guild this bot is installed on.

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!! I know this is too much, but could you also help me with the database function? I'm new here :DD, anyways, I'll let my discord here (Loan#2334) if it's easier for you to help me there.

Comment: @Luisikoman sent you a friend request. approve me and we'll continue there